# Why is this metaclass modifying the values only after the constructor executes?

Tags: groovy, constructor, metaclass

```
class EmailAssist {
    def abcService = "abc"
    String name

    EmailAssist(String name) {
        this.name = name
        println abcService
    }

    EmailAssist() {
    }

}

EmailAssist.metaClass.getAbcService = {->
    "test"
}

def e = new EmailAssist("Joe")
println e.abcService
```

This results in output of

```
abc
test
```

I'd think it would result in

```
test
test
```

Can anyone explain what goes into this exactly?  Does the metaclass only modify after the constructor executes, as opposed to overwriting constructor methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a class (not inner/nested class, not open block) that defines a field and you access the field using a qualified or unqualified `this`, then the access is done directly without considering the MOP. Thus you cannot shadow a field in this manner. Since this logic is done by the compiler and literal, instead of by value you can bypass this through `def tmp = this; tmp.abcService`